# postgres database : Insufficient privilege, permission denied for relation table

Tags: database, postgresql, laravel, heroku

I have been using the postgres database on heroku for a while. and suddenly I had some problems on saving to database 
I got this error all the time

```
 Insufficient privilege, permission denied for relation table
```

its a problem of user permission , but I'm confused why it happened , because it was working correctly before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `heroku pg:info` output - chances are you've exceeded the free plan permitted number of rows (assuming you're using a hobby-basic)

Comment: thank you , that was very helpful , Can the problem be solved by reducing the records on database ( staging) ?

Comment: Yes, if you reduce rows to <10000 for hobby-basic (Free one) then you'll get write access granted again.